# How can I call UiPath data Service API in Angular 15

Tags: uipath, uipath-api, uipath-apps

My requirement is, we have developed an API using UiPath Data Service so that on form submit form data can store in UiPath entity. My web form is developed in Angular 15. My question is how can I call the data API in Angular?

We are using UiPath Orchestra service for data service.